# Проблема strtok C++11

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, xubuntu

Написал свою функцию `split` (Как, например, в Java или Python):

```
   char **split(char *str, char *tok, int *len) {
        char **out = new char*[1];
        (*len) = 0;

        char *token = strtok(str, tok);

        while (token != nullptr) {
            out[(*len)++] = token;

            char **copy = new char*[(*len) + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < (*len); i++)
                copy[i] = out[i];

            delete[] out;
            out = copy;

            token = strtok(0, tok);
        }

        return out;
    }

    int main() {
        int len = 0;
        char **dataBase = split("asdasd asd asdasdasd asdasd asdasd asdadsasd asd", " ", &len);

        return 0;
    }
```

Однако, не работает - код ошибки 139, из-за строки `char *token = strtok(str, tok);` (проверил в дебагере). Вопрос: что я делаю не так?

Comment: Это задача, или надо решить реальную проблему? Почему бы не использовать `boost::split`  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не знаю что такое "код ошибки 139", но сразу бросается в глаза, что в качестве первого аргумента вы передаёте строку, которую изменять нельзя. На попытке вызвать для неё `strtok()` код, очевидно, грохнется с чем-нибудь вроде `Segmentation fault`.

P.S. Ну и да, *так* велосипедить в C++ - смысл?

Answer (score 2):

Вы не хотите - раз уж у вас С++ - получать `vector<string>`? Это куда логичнее, никаких утечек памяти, никаких проблем с освобождением потом...

Исправлять ваш код сложно, потому что вы в нем запутались в массиве указателей и делаете совсем не то - его надо переписывать. Но если уж это С++ (более того, С++11, как вы сами пишете) - то проще сделать так, если уж хотите получить массив строк:

```
vector<string> split(const char *str, const char *tok)
{
    vector<string> res;
    string s(str);
    for(char *token = strtok(s.data(),tok);
        token;token = strtok(nullptr,tok))
    {
        res.emplace_back(token);
    }
    return res;
}
```